# Sort IP address

Tags: ios, iphone, sorting, networking, ip

I'm working on an application which scan the wi-fi network and list the ip list and device connected.

I tried to sort the ip list by creating two new object properties ip4thOctet and ip3thOctet and make the sort after depend of them.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger ip4thOctet;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger ip3thOctet;
```

and:

```
-(NSInteger)ip4thOctet {
    if (self.ipAddress) {
            return [[[self.ipAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject] intValue];
    }
    return 0;
}

-(NSInteger)ip3thOctet {
    if (self.ipAddress) {
        NSInteger elements = [[self.ipAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] count];
        return [[[self.ipAddress componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:elements-1] intValue];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Based on these properties I tried to sort the array:

```
-(void)lanScanDidFindNewDevice:(Device*)device {
    if (![connectedDevicesMutable containsObject:device]) {
        [connectedDevicesMutable addObject:device];
    }

    self.connectedDevices = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:connectedDevicesMutable];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ip4thOctet"
                                                 ascending:YES
                                                  selector:@selector(compare:)
                      ];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
    self.connectedDevices = [self.connectedDevices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor3thIpOctect = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ip3thOctet"
                                                 ascending:YES
                                                  selector:@selector(compare:)
                      ];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors3th = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor3thIpOctect];
    self.connectedDevices = [self.connectedDevices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors3th];
}
```

The client expected result should looks like :

Expected:

172.17.0.1

172.17.0.2

172.17.1.1

172.17.1.3

172.17.3.1

Can you help me to sort the ip list according with client expectation, please ?

The current result is :

172.17.0.1

172.17.1.1

172.17.3.1

172.17.0.2

172.17.1.2

172.17.0.3

172.17.1.3

Comment: What is your current sorted output, in what way differs it from the expectation?

Comment: the current result is : 172.17.0.1
172.17.1.1
172.17.3.1
172.17.0.2
172.17.1.2
172.17.0.3
172.17.1.3

Comment: IPv4 addresses are really 32-bit, unsigned integers, and you should use that to sort them. The dotted-decimal notation is really only to make it easier for humans to read, and you should not use that in an application that is trying to manipulate or use IPv4 addresses. The octets actually have no real meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `objectAtIndex:elements-1` in `ip3thOctet` you are accessing the last element (start counting at 0). So you are both times sorting for the last element. You should use `elements-2`.